# Split datetime from string android

Tags: android, split, substring

I have `String s  = http://kqxs.net.vn/xo-so-ngay/an-giang-xsag-23-4-2015/`

(Using Java android)how to split date string 23-4-2015 from it become two substring:

1. http://kqxs.net.vn/xo-so-ngay/an-giang-xsag
2. 23-4-2015

Answer (score 1):

Use the `substring` method

```
    String str = "http://kqxs.net.vn/xo-so-ngay/an-giang-xsag-23-4-2015/";
    url = str.substring(0, 43);
    date = str.substring(44, 53);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the date will always be on the last. So you can actualy do Java substring take the last 11 char from the end. Because there is "/".

Hard way you can actually do a RegEx to get only a number. But it is not possible if in the URL there is a numerical too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using regular expressions,

```
String str = "http://kqxs.net.vn/xo-so-ngay/an-giang-xsag-23-4-2015/";
        String regexStr = "\\d{2}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{4}";


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexStr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);


        int startIndex=-1;
        // Check all occurrences
        while (matcher.find()) {
            startIndex = matcher.start();
        }

        if(startIndex>0){
            String firstPart = str.substring(0,startIndex-1);
            String secondPart = str.substring(startIndex);
            System.out.println("First Part "+firstPart);
            System.out.println("Second Part "+secondPart);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Match Not Found!");
        }
```

Output:-
First Part http://kqxs.net.vn/xo-so-ngay/an-giang-xsag
Second Part 23-4-2015/

Answer (score 0):

Try This code for The Get the date from the String.

```
String str="fgdfg12°59'50\" Nfr | gdfg: 80°15'25\" Efgd";
String[] spitStr= str.split("\\|");

String numberOne= spitStr[0].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
String numberSecond= spitStr[1].replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

Try this another code

```
String str=" abc d 1234567890pqr 54897";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+([0-9]+)\\w+([0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
for(int i = 0 ; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
  matcher.find();
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```